# Change lock key status lights

Tags: assembly, operating-system, nasm

How do I turn on and off the status lights on the lock keys (Caps Lock, Num Lock, and Scroll Lock) from a stand-alone [NASM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netwide_Assembler) file (no operating system)?

I know that `xset` can be used inside a Linux terminal, and that other operating systems have other methods of turning on and off the status lights. But how do I do it without an operating system?

Comment: Status light on a (PC) ***[keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_PC_keyboard)***, presumably? Re *"no operating system"*: What about a [BIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS)? Are there presumptions about a BIOS abstraction? For a [PS/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_port) and/or USB keyboard? What hardware is presumed? Some standard [PC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Personal_Computer) hardware?

Comment: Is the presumption a [PS/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_port) keyboard (not a USB keyboard) connected to a PC?

Answer (score 2):

This standalone file will turn on the Caps Lock, Scroll Lock, and Num Lock keyboard lights.

```
; blinklights.asm

[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x7C00]

jmp Code_Start


Switch_Kbd_Leds:

    push dx     ; Store current values.
    push ax

    mov dx, 60h ; '60h' is the 'kbd' port value.
    mov al, 0EDh    ; '0EDh' is 'set/reset leds' function.
    out dx, al  ; Output to the port.

    pop ax      ; Get the setting from the stack.
    out dx, al  ; Output to the port.

    pop dx      ; Restore 'dx'.
    ret     ; Return.

Code_Start:
    mov al, 00000111b
    call Switch_Kbd_Leds


    jmp $       

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

The way it works is that `al` contains the bits to turn on or off certain lights:

```
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- caps num  scrl
 0    0    0    0    0    x    x    x
```

This line turns on the Caps, Num, and Scroll Lock lights:

```
mov al, 00000111b
```

Finally, a call to the keyboard port `60h` with "Set/Reset LEDs" (`0EDh`) changes the values.

Comment: What is the context? Where does it run? How is it made to run? Put in the [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record)? How is it compiled? Under [FreeDOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeDOS)?